# How to set radius for all corners of Simplee Drawee Android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

Not able to set radius for all the corners of `SimpleDrawee` of `facebook` android sdk.
What i have Tried:-

```
RoundingParams roundingParams = RoundingParams.fromCornersRadii(8f,8f,8f,8f);
            mSimpleDrawee.setHierarchy(new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(getResources())
                    .setRoundingParams(roundingParams)
                    .build());
```

Also tried setting in xml :

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:roundedCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                />
```

But both are setting only top left corner radius.

Comment: What is `simpledrawee`? AFAIK android does not provide any widget named as `simpledraweeview`. If your question is about Facebook's simpledraweeview then add this with question also add proper tag for it.

Comment: Yes its for facebook only

Answer (score 0):

Have a drawable like `rounded_corners.xml` under drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/primary" />
<corners android:radius="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then try to set this to the layout you need the rounded corners like

`android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_4"`

Answer (score 0):

**Add in your xml layout**

android:background="@drawable/round_corner"

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<corners android:radius="15dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Imageview code in your xml hope it will be work

```
 <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"                
      fresco:roundedCornerRadius="10dp"
      fresco:roundTopLeft="true"
      fresco:roundTopRight="true"
      fresco:roundBottomLeft="true"
      fresco:roundBottomRight="true"
      fresco:roundTopStart="true"
      fresco:roundTopEnd="true"
      fresco:roundBottomStart="true"
      fresco:roundBottomEnd="true"
      />
```

Comment: remove this line android:adjustViewBounds="true" and try again

Comment: no help with this also, only top left and bottom left get rounded

Comment: So now alternative solution is use card view as parent and put SimpleDraweeView  that

Answer (score 0):

There is two params `app:roundBottomStart` and  `app:roundBottomEnd` you set both of theme to true in your **xml** and you will get a rounded corner on all your image

```
  app:roundedCornerRadius="8dp"
  app:roundBottomStart="false"
  app:roundBottomEnd="false"
```